# returning image file from image data in php

Tags: php, imagedata

thank you for responding ;

I have image data in **$snap** , the content of **$snap** is like this :

**data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAA**... etc

I need that my php file return **$snap** as image file ; when the example-image.php oppend it shoud be like example.jpg

this is the script I want to respond to it :

```
jQuery.get(domainPath+'&getImage&site='+inputHost,function(data){
     $("#screenshotData").html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+data+'"/>');
});
```

The script above will use my respond to make an img html tag , I **can't** change the script above ; **my respond shoud make the script above applicable .**

Comment: use `base64_decode($snap);` and then save that in a file like `file.jpg`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since your JavaScript code is expecting base64 content, you should be able to just echo it from your PHP script--after removing the part that you don't need.

```php
<?php

$snap = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAA...';

// remove the prefix 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' because JavaScript is prepending this
$data = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $snap);

// output the data
echo $data;
```

Comment: Why even bother replacing it in the data, why not just remove the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` from the JavaScript? If we are delivering images as base64 already, which will bloat the data to roughly about 4/3 of its original binary size, then this is probably not the place where a handful of bytes desperately need saving now in transport.

Comment: @CBroe, because the OP stated "I can't change the script above". Which I think means that the JavaScript cannot be adjusted.